# Scala: class takes type parameters when passing a class to another class?

Tags: scala, runnable, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a runnable class to use with threads. The purpose of the class is to take a [KafkaStream](https://people.apache.org/%7Ejoestein/kafka-0.7.1-incubating-docs/kafka/consumer/KafkaStream.html) and apply a function to every message that comes through the stream, but when I try to pass a stream to the class I get the following compiler error: "scala:45: class KafkaStream takes type parameters".

```
class streamOperator extends Runnable {
  def run(f: String => Any, stream: KafkaStream) {
    for (messageAndTopic <- stream) {
      var message = new String(messageAndTopic.message)
      f(message)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the class. The issue must be something to do with how to pass parameters to a class in Scala, but I'm am still new to Scala.

Additionally is it possible to make a function runnable? I assume it would be easier to pass to a function than a class.

Comment: Unlike Java Scala doesn't have raw types, so you have to use _some_ type parameter in `stream: KafkaStream[?]`. What the `?` should be depends on what you're expecting `messageAndTopic.message` to be.

Comment: @TravisBrown ahh ok, I figured it was something like this. messageAndTopic is an Array[Bytes], but when I tried `KafkaStream[Array[Byte]]` I am now getting "wrong number of arguments for kafka.consumer.KafkaStream, should be 1". Do I need to be supplying what should be coming out of KafkaStream, or what should be going into it?

Comment: Or have the caller provide the type: `def run[T](f: String => Any, stream: KafkaStream[T])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was, as suggested in the comments, to pass KafkaStream[?]. In this case the ? was `KafkaStream[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]`. I think `KafkaStream[T]` would work as well, but I think its better to pass the actual types if possible.